# Missing Migration data in SQL when trying to add-migration

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, database-migration, code-first

I have made use of a backup database and have added a new table using Code First. Now when I tried using add-migration, I got this error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending

Suggesting that the Migrations in the project do not match which are in the DB, which when I looked, there are NO migrations in the __migration table any more ?

As these tables exist in the DB, how do I get all of these migrations inserted into my SQL DB ? Is there a way I can get them all added, so that the projects migrations and the SQL DB migrations will match, so that I can continue adding/editing tables ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found something that did help! It unfortunately meant that I lost all of my migration files, but thats not the end of the world.

The below is reference from this site: [Click here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate)

> - Remove the _MigrationHistory table from the Database
> - Remove the individual migration files in your project's Migrations folder
> - Enable-Migrations in Package Manager Console
> - Add-migration Initial in PMC
> - Comment out the code inside of the Up method in the Initial Migration
> - Update-database in PMC (does nothing but creates Migration Entry)
> - Remove comments in the Initial method

I hope this helps someone else as well.